# Total Wildcard DNS vHosts To 1 File

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I'm looking to set a vhosts config so that all domains under ANY ip all point to var/www/index.php so that I can sort them from there... I'm sure this is pretty simple to do but it's hard to search google for that specific question ;)

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't originally clear but I need anything file request to go to var/www, example: sub.domain.com/lol.php would request index.php...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be what the standard Apache config does! No need for any vhosts at all, just a basic config listening on port 80 without specifying the IP address to listen on.

Comment: And in your index.php, you can sort them out with $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], because the vhost name will be in there.

Comment: I've just tried this and although any domain/sub points to index file, when I try and do domain.com/lol.php it says file not found. I need everything to go to index.php.

Comment: As explained below by Boohbah, mod rewrite will add the final piece for you.

Comment: You can simply make lol.php to be a symlink to index.php too, no need for mod_rewrite IMHO

Comment: Using mod_alias is another alternative

Answer (score 1):

You must set this in your apache config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

The FIRST vhost definition in your apache config is the one it falls back to if none of the others match. 
I have a config file called (they are included sorted by filename on CentOS 5).

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/000-Default-webhoster.basjes.nl.conf
```

I have something like this as the first Vhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/Default/
    ServerName webhoster.basjes.nl
    UseCanonicalName on
    CookieTracking on
    CookieDomain .basjes.nl
</VirtualHost>
```

and there you can handle anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect requests for lol.php to index.php using a mod_rewrite rule.
First, enable mod_rewrite.

httpd.conf:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

(This part varies depending on your OS.)

mod_rewrite for Ubuntu:

```
# a2enmod rewrite && /etc/init.d/apache2 force-reload
```

The create an .htaccess file in your DocumentRoot.

```
#.htaccess code
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: This server is going to be getting upwards of 50k hits/day.. I've heard modrewrite decreases performance and I'd rather avoid that, can I just put the rule in vhosts?

Comment: Not if you want to redirect lol.php to index.php.

Comment: 50k hits is not a lot.  The impact of the rewrite rule would be negligible.

Comment: Another option would be to set index.html as your error page for 404s - total hack, and it would result in a return code of 404 rather than 200 - but if you really want to avoid mod rewrite, that would do it. Though, like skraggy says, with only 50k hits I doubt you have anything to worry about with mod rewrite - unless your server is very very old and crappy of course :)